# Are there limits to size for a Warshaper's Morphic Weapons feature?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, creature-size, class, natural-weapon

Is there any limit to how much a Warshaper (Complete Warrior) can grow their limbs using their Morphic Weapons ability? As far as the rules say, it is possible for a Tiny creature to then grow to Colossal weapons with enough move actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the ability: (Emphasis mine)

> Morphic Weapons (Su): As a move action, a warshaper can grow natural weapons such as claws or fangs, **allowing a natural attack that deals the appropriate amount of damage according to the size of the new form (see Table 5—1 on page 296 of the Monster Manual).** These morphic weapons need not be natural weapons that the creature already possesses. For example, a warshaper polymorphed into an ettin (Large giant) could grow a claw that deals 1d6 points of damage, or horns for a gore attack that deals 1d8 points of damage.
>   If the warshaper's form **already has a natural weapon of that type, the weapon deals damage as if it were one category larger.** For example, a warshaper who used wild shape to become a dire wolf (Large animal) could grow its jaw and snout, enabling a bite attack that deals 2d6 points of damage (as a for Huge animal), not the normal 1d8.
>   A warshaper can change morphic weapons as often as it likes, even if it is using a shapechanging technique such as the polymorph spell or the wild shape class feature that doesn't allow subsequent changes after the initial transformation.

I understand  from the description that you can grow natural weapons according to the size of the shape you turn into, or if the shape you turned into already has natural weapons, you can enhance them to act as ONLY one size category larger. So I believe, that it's actually a matter of what kind of shape you chose to turn into, as the prestige class has a shapechanger type perequisite.

Comment: Yes, one size category larger... on this use of the ability. But if you use the ability again, your form already has a natural weapon of that type (you just grew it), so you can increase its size, can’t you? Which is, I think, @Garan’s question.

Comment: Important bit here, it deals damage "AS IF" it was one size larger. The weapon doesn't actually increase in size category.

Comment: @aslum except the ability text gives us contradictory fluff : "a warshaper [...] could grow its jaw and snout". It's just fluff but it helps understand what was intended.

Comment: @KRyan The ability is Supernatural so can't stack on itself. Using it a second time on a weapon that has already benefited from this ability will have the effects overlap.

Comment: @Chemus Reasonable argument, but the answer needs to *make* the argument. And there are counterarguments, since morphic weapons explicitly says that the weapon grows relative to whatever form it had before. Ultimately, you’re probably right RAW, and obviously it’s broken to allow it to self-stack, but I think an answer to this question should get into that discussion.

Comment: @KRyan Fair enough. As it appears unlikely that the answer author will be back soon... Working...

Answer (score 3):

> **Morphic Weapons (Su):** [...] If the warshaper's form already has a natural weapon of that type, the weapon deals damage as if it were one category larger.

It totally depends on how you understand *"the warshaper's form"* :

1. if you consider it's the current form of the warshaper, using Morphic Weapon actually increase the natural weapon size each time you use it.
2. if you consider it's the existing form the warshaper shaped into (like a Dire Wolf), then using Morphic Weapon on the Large natural weapon of the Dire Wolf just makes it Huge, no matter how many time you use it.

I think the second option is what rules intended, but as they are written, nothing prevents you from using the first option.

Next questions are: can the increase in size of the natural weapon change creature's size ? What a kitty with a Colossal bite attack looks like ?

**EDIT** about the *"as if"* highlighted by @aslum's comment :

Although the ability says that a warshaper assuming a dire wolf shape may "grow his jaw and snout", it also says that only damage must be considered as if the weapon was one size bigger, so there's no real size augmentation, and a kitty with a Colossal bite attack just has the sharpest-est teeth ever. So the above questions are unfounded, but I leave them here.

Comment: The example text in the rules to me implies the second interpretation is the best fit, as does your thought experiment of Tiny animal with Colossal bite.

Comment: I believe it is the second too, because in the first case it refers to the form as the New Form, while on the second it is just a form. I think that it is some kind of typo.

Comment: Surely that should be a rabbit with a colossal bite?

Answer (score 2):

### Only one effective size increase per pre-existing weapon

The Morphic Weapons ability of the Warshaper (*Complete Warrior*, 90), is a supernatural ability, and as such is limited by the Combining Magical Effects rules (*Player's Handbook*, [171-2](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#same-effect-more-than-once-in-different-strengths)), most notably the *Same effect More Than Once in Different Strengths* and the *Same Effect with Differing Results* sections.

The pertinent sections of the Morphic Weapons ability are (all emphases mine):

> [...] a warshaper can grow natural weapons such as claws or fangs, allowing a natural attack that deals the appropriate amount of damage according to the size of the ***new form*** [...] . These morphic weapons need not be natural weapons that the creature already possesses[...]
> If the ***warshaper’s form*** already has a natural weapon of that type, ***the weapon*** deals damage **as if** ***it*** were one category larger.

The *new form* mentioned is also the *warshaper's form* referenced later; the form that the warshaper is using that permits the use of the class abilities in the first place

> The class features function only when the warshaper is in a form other than her own [...]

The *it* in *deals damage as if it were one size category larger* is in reference to the warshaper's form rather than the weapon's size. Additionally, the increase in size is simply an effective increase of damage only, not a change for any other purposes.

The warshaper can't modify the natural weapons that it adds to the form, because first, the form doesn't have the weapons without the ability and the ability has separate rules for both situations, and second, the ability can't stack on itself, simply overlap, due to Combining Effects rules.